# Excel Formula..could not change the text

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I am using this formula to make an hyperlink for the path that is in AN column

```
=IF(ISBLANK(AN5),"",HYPERLINK(AN5,"(resume)"))
```

each row (AN1,AN2,AN3....) will have different paths and I want hyperlinks at Am1,AM2,AM3 .....for those paths. This formula worked fine for the whole column and the hyperlinks are working fine.

But the only thing is I could not change the hyperlink text "resume" to a different name like "Work history"..

When I change the name in the formula it is applying to only one cell that I changed but not to the whole column.

Answer (score 0):

You have to click on the bottom right corner of the cell, and drag the formula through the entire column (where the formula already is) and it will replace them all.

Comment: quicker than dragging: DOUBLE-CLICK the little black square at the bottom right of the cell you need to copy. It will fill like magic till the first blank row.

Comment: ya..but it changes for the cells that already have the link but not for the new ones.

Comment: @user397316, you'll need to be clearer on what you mean by "new ones"

Answer (score 0):

Is the worksheet in Manual calculation mode? DO you see the word "Calculate" in the lower left hand corner? Hit f9 to recalculate the worksheet.